# Export JSON To CSV based on Row and Column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, export-to-csv

https://ibb.co/pZQDLBv

I have a Calendar data using react-CSV library in React. I need to export the data not just column-based but also based on row.
Here is the CSV format I am trying to form
https://ibb.co/hRjKGYh

I have an array of Header List data containing around 50+ City names

```
const resourceId = ["Sydney", "Hyderabad", "London", "Tokyo", etc"]
```

Header To be feeded To CSV

```
header_data = [{label: "resourceId", key: "resourceId"}]
```

I have a JSON Object structure like this

```
const result =  [

{
    resourceId: "Berlin”, 
    title: “Test1”, 
    name: “Foo1”, 
    startTime: Fri Jan 10 2020 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 
    endTime: Fri Jan 10 2020 11:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
    timezone: "Asia/Singapore”
},
{
    resourceId: “Tokyo”, 
    title: “Test2”, 
    name: “Bar1”, 
    startTime: Fri Jan 10 2020 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 
    endTime: Fri Jan 10 2020 11:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
    timezone: "Asia/Singapore”
},
{
    resourceId: “Hyderabad”, 
    title: “Test3”, 
    name: "Foo2”, 
    startTime: Fri Jan 10 2020 13:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 
    endTime: Fri Jan 10 2020 15:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
    timezone: "Asia/Singapore”
}]
```

24hours Time format for StartTime column data

```
const start_time_column = ["00:00AM", "00:30AM", "01:00AM", "01:30AM", "02:00AM", "02:30AM", "03:00AM", "03:30AM", "04:00AM", "04:30AM", "05:00AM", "05:30AM", "06:00AM", "06:30AM", "07:00AM", "07:30AM", "08:00AM", "08:30AM", "09:00AM", "09:30AM", "10:00AM", "10:30AM", "11:00AM", "11:30AM", "00:00PM", "00:30PM", "01:00PM", "01:30PM", "02:00PM", "02:30PM", "03:00PM", "03:30PM", "04:00PM", "04:30PM", "05:00PM", "05:30PM", "06:00PM", "06:30PM", "07:00PM", "07:30PM", "08:00PM", "08:30PM", "09:00PM", "09:30PM", "10:00PM", "10:30PM", "11:00PM", "11:30PM"]
```

JSX TAG

```
    <CSVLink
      data={result}
      headers={header_data}
      filename={"test.csv"}
    >
      <Button
        icon="export"
        intent="primary"
        text="Export"
      />
    </CSVLink>
```

Here is the CSV format I m trying to form.

I am trying to export this Calendar data as it is to CSV format 
For example -  If an event is from 13:00PM to 15:30PM for resourceID Hyderabad, it should fill cells to the corresponding rows with

Start Time index of Row with Start Time 13:00PM to Row with Start Time 15:30PM with data-  13:30-15:30 Hyderabad Test3 Fool2.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by export "as row"? I'm trying to figure out what you expect the export to contain, or what an example of that might look like. I'm not getting the connections b/w the issue and the linked image. Thanks.

Comment: @Todd I have updated my question and here is the screenshot link of CSV format I am trying to achieve. https://ibb.co/hRjKGYh 
Export as Row to fill the specific cells.

Comment: I believe that you will need to invoke an intermediary transformation function in the `onClick` property of your csvlink component. The purpose of the function will be to take your object array and start_time_column array, and combine them into a single array of arrays, adding the result title, etc., where the start_time_column[i] value is within the range of the startTime and endTime. Unfortunately, I don't believe that this library has anything to automagically do this transformation for you.

Comment: I think considering a more conventional format is your best option. is there a reason that you wouldn't simply want a new row for each event, sorted by ascending start time? like this: https://technologyaround.me/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/2017-09-29-21_24_56-import-template-college-google-calendar.csv-Excel-1024x331.png

Comment: @Todd Yes, the reason I don't want this is specifically for user requirements. They want to see events at a particular time frame and the users engaged. Example - They want to see what are the events from 3-5 pm, who all are occupied in that or something else. The format in the screenshot, I already have it. Does not fulfill the requirement.